# SQL Server Data cleaning

Tags: sql, sql-server, data-mining, data-cleaning

please I want your help
I will start working on data mining project using sql server for database. 
I have big database and before I start working on my project for sure I need to do data cleaning on my database, so 
please I want your suggestions what I need to do, like removing duplicate, and removing spaces from some columns ? what else and what I need to do to be sure that my data are ready to start working on it with data mining process like clustering and decisions tree ......

- Also please if you have any useful videos for Data mining in general using SQL Server Management studio - sql server  cleaning data

Thanks a lot in Advance...

Comment: You need to divide your requests into smaller parts and add examples of your datatables/database, if you want our help. This is way too big of a ask

Answer (score 1):

If you want to delete duplicates, you can use recursive CTE. I recommend this website for further information on how to: [SQLServerTutorial](https://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-basics/delete-duplicates-from-a-table-in-sql-server/)

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT 
        YourColumns
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
            PARTITION BY 
                YourColumns
            ORDER BY 
                YourColumns 
        ) row_num
     FROM 
        YourTable
)
DELETE FROM cte
WHERE row_num > 1;
```

Regarding removing blank spaces, I recommend `TRIM, LTRIM & RTRIM`. For further information: [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_ref_sqlserver.asp)

```
SELECT TRIM(Column) FROM YourTable
```